# Unable to send data to BeagleBone via serial uart cable, login and password on First Use, but it reicive log massages over minicom

Tags: beagleboneblack

I bought Beagle Bone Black.
I conneted Serial cable (CP2102) to beagle bone.
I am able to get log massages over minicom(console).
But I am Not able to send data (login and Password ) to Beagle Bone Black.

Answer (score 1):

I get Solution Myself.

I changed minicom setting. Hardware flow control was enabled.

Solution : I disabled Hardware flow control in minicom setting.

If hardware flow control enabled. Then minicom will not able to send data to beaglebone black via serial cable. Minicom will take log maggages from beaglebone.

Answer (score 0):

worked after disabling Hardware flow control in minicom setting